# Rake task for auto-migrating Engine migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm now developing a Rails Application with Engines mounted in.

I thoughed it would be a good idea to code a rake tast, which will copy the migrations from the Engine and run a rake db:migrate.

However, if I run the rake task with just one Engine in the engines-Arry (see below), the rake tast will copy the migrations from the Engine and migrate the db. But if I add another Engine to the array, the rake-Task won't work anymore.

```
namespace :work_in_progress do
  desc 'Migrate the engines db tables'
  task migrate_migrations_from_engines: :environment do
    # The array with the available engines (just add the new engine here)
    engines = [
      'engine_one',
      'engine_two'
    ]

    puts 'Migrating migrations from engines...'
    engines.each do |engine|
      puts 'Copying migrations from ' + engine
      Rake::Task[engine + ':install:migrations'].invoke
    end
    puts 'Migrating the database...'
    Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
    puts 'Done...'
  end

end
```

How do I improve the script above, so that more than one engine can me migrated?
Are there other scripts around solving this issue (copying migrations from Engines and run them?)?

Thank you very much!

Philipp

Comment: No. No error. There are just the "puts" written to the console, but nothing else happens.

Comment: Try `execute` instead of `invoke`.

Comment: @pmuens: have u tried the solution mentioned in answer.

Comment: @AmanGarg your execute doesn't work, sorry. But I've tried the answer below which does the trick for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to run rake tasks to install migrations and then run those. Try this code to execute the tasks:

```
namespace :work_in_progress do
  desc 'Migrate the engines db tables'
  task migrate_migrations_from_engines: :environment do
    # The array with the available engines (just add the new engine here)
    engines = ['engine_one','engine_two']
    puts 'Migrating migrations from engines...'
    engines.each do |engine|
      puts 'Copying migrations from ' + engine
      `bundle exec rake #{engine}:install:migrations`      
    end
    puts 'Migrating the database...'
    `bundle exec rake db:migrate`      
    puts 'Done...'
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution works!
For everyone who reads this: Be aware of the 'special' titled quotes. Otherwise, it won't work!

Comment: Would be interested in finding out why the original does not run. Ran into the exact same issue.